# How to design api endpoints on a website with auto save?

Tags: java, c#, rest, restful-url

I have a website where each company can modify some settings: UpperBanner, LowerBanner, Introduction or TextSize. Each of these fields has auto save. Should I create endpoints for each field?

This is a table in my database:
[image]

This is a design of my website (**each field has auto save**):
[image]

I consider the following endpoints. Is it a good direction?

```
GET /PageSettings - to return a row in a database for a company
HEAD /PageSettings - to check if exists a row in a database for a company
POST /PageSettings - to create a row in a database with only Id and CompanyId

HEAD /PageSettings/UpperBanner/{FileId} - to check if exists UpperBanner in a database for a company
POST /PageSettings/UpperBanner - to add UpperBanner in a database for a company
PUT /PageSettings/UpperBanner/{FileId} - to change UpperBanner in a database for a company

HEAD /PageSettings/LowerBanner/{FileId} - to check if exists LowerBanner in a database for a company
POST /PageSettings/LowerBanner - to add LowerBanner in a database for a company
PUT /PageSettings/LowerBanner/{FileId} - to change LowerBanner in a database for a company

HEAD /PageSettings/Introduction - to check if exists Introduction in a database for a company
POST /PageSettings/Introduction - to add Introduction in a database for a company
PUT /PageSettings/Introduction - to change Introduction in a database for a company

HEAD /PageSettings/TextSize - to check if exists TextSize in a database for a company
POST /PageSettings/TextSize - to add TextSize in a database for a company
PUT /PageSettings/TextSize - to change TextSize in a database for a company
```

Comment: Maybe you can consider to use the HTTP method [PATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH)?

Comment: I have files so I wonder if PATH be easy.

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to create a single CRUD endpoint whose PUT/PATCH operation updates only the information sent. In this case, you must differentiate when a field that may be null has or has not been sent.

If you eliminate the possibility of having null elements, the merge is trivial:

```
@Controller
... MyControllerClass {

    @Put / @Patch
    public Response upsert(Entity upsertEntity) {
        ...
        Entity currentEntity = repository
            .get(upsertEntity.getId())
            .merge(upsertEntity);
        ...
        repository.save(currentEntity);
```

where the `Entity.merge` operation is like:

```
class Entity {
    ...
    public Entity merge(Entity other) {
        if(other.getField1() != null) setField1(other.getField1());
        if(other.getField2() != null) setField1(other.getField2());
        ...
        // merge hierarchy
        if(other.getFieldX() != null)
            getFieldX().merge(other.getFieldX());
        ...
        return this;
```

if the fields can be removed to the `null` state, this approach does not work and you cannot use the same persistence entities for your API (like Spring Boot Forms for many cases you need a wrapper).

Thus, if the client wants to update N fields, it can do so with a single operation. If when a user makes a change you wait X seconds, you can detect and accumulate multiple changes to be sent all together.

If you need reset fields (set to null) create a specific type for the single operation:

```
class UpsertRequestData {
    private boolean resetField1; // or `field1IsPresent`
    private Field1Type field1;
    private boolean resetField2;
    private Field2Type field2;
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly each field can be null :(

Comment: Then as I said, wrap your data for each field instead create an entire endpoint.